# Converting raw print codes to a printer using a VB.net web page

Tags: vb.net, printing

I've run into a situation I've never encountered before. I'm working with a shipping API for an e-commerce site and I've retrieved a shipping label. The problem is that the code used for the label is what appears to be raw print codes. They look something like this:

```
N
Q822,24
R40,0
S4
D15
ZB

A760,120,1,1,1,1,N,"Interlink Express"
A735,080,1,1,1,1,N,"www.interlinkexpress.com"
A706,033,1,1,1,1,N,"Sender"
.... more codes like this
LO001,330,765,10
LO001,025,765,1
LO001,192,590,1
LO001,330,765,10
.... more codes like this
P1
```

What I'd like to be able to do is convert it to a graphic or something else that I can print from a web page. The problem is that I can't find any ways to deal with this particular type of information, since it's not in a web-standard format (it's not HTML, XML, JSON, etc.)

How would I deal with something like this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you treat it as a string? Then you can use some SDK for making files like `iTextSharp` or `PDFSharp`.

Comment: These are the low-level printing instructions for a Zebra printer.  Call the company, good odds that they've heard this request before.

Comment: Call Zebra or call Interlink? I was thinking of calling Interlink anyway.

Answer (score -1):

In the end, I solved this a different way. Apparently the shipping company was able to use an Accept: text/html header from my HttpWebRequest and I got an HTML-formatted printer label. So we're good. Thanks.